# Docker does not create a new container when using docker-compose build

Tags: windows, powershell, docker

I've set up two windows container for ASP.NET and MSSQL server. On the first docker-compose build everything works as expected. Then after I've made some changes to the custom dockerfile and run docker-compose build again it uses the old container again, not making any changes.

I assumed that when i did a build it created a new container. Am i misunderstanding how docker works?

This is the docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3'
services:
  db:
    image: microsoft/mssql-server-windows-developer

    environment:
      sa_password: "Password1234!"
      ACCEPT_EULA: "Y"

    ports:
      - "8003:1433"
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: mssql.dockerfile

  web:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: web.dockerfile
    image: mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/framework/aspnet:4.8
    #volumes:
    #  - .:C:/inetpub/wwwroot
    ports: 
      - "8080:80"
      - "8081:431"
```

This is the mssql.dockerfile

```
# escape=`

FROM microsoft/mssql-server-windows-developer

#set shell
SHELL ["powershell.exe", "-Command", "$ErrorActionPreference = 'Stop'; $ProgressPreference = 'SilentlyContinue';"]

#make temp folder
RUN mkdir C:\temp

#copy script to temp folder
COPY DownloadDatabase.ps1 C:\temp
COPY RestoreDatabase.ps1 C:\temp

#run script to retrieve production database
WORKDIR C:\temp

RUN .\DownloadDatabase.ps1 -sourcefile <url> -destinationfile <target>

CMD .\RestoreDatabase.ps1
```

It is very easy to tell if the image has been re-used because the mkdir C:\temp errors out saying the directory already exists.

EDIT: I've already tried all the options on docker compose. no-cache, force-rm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out i simply had to do `docker-compose pull` before `docker-compose build` to refresh the dockerfile! Now it builds a fresh image every time!

Answer (score 4):

```
docker-compose build
```

**Only builds images** but **does not start containers.**

That's why your changes in dockerfile are not applied. You have rebuilded the image but not the container. It's the reason why the container previoulsy launched is based on the older version of the image.

```
docker-compose up
```

From Docker [documentation](https://docs.docker.com/compose/reference/up/) :

> If there are existing containers for a service, and the service’s configuration or image was changed after the container’s creation, docker-compose up picks up the changes by stopping and recreating the containers (preserving mounted volumes). To prevent Compose from picking up changes, use the --no-recreate flag.

In order to make shure that both of your image and container are rebuilded you have to add this flags :

```
docker-compose up --force-recreate --build
```

That way your containers are based on the correct image version.

Explanation on flags from Docker [documentation](https://docs.docker.com/compose/reference/up/) :

```
--build                   Build images before starting containers.

--force-recreate          Recreate containers even if their configuration
                          and image haven't changed.
```

If you want to do this for a specific service just add the service name at the end of command line :

```
docker-compose up --force-recreate --build serviceName
```

Another flag useful if you want a clear output is the `-d` flag :

```
 -d, --detach              Detached mode: Run containers in the background,
                           print new container names. Incompatible with
```

Comment: I've tried to rebuild the image with `docker-compose up --force-recreate --build` but that gives me the same error as when i do build:

`Step 3/7 : RUN mkdir C:\temp ---> Running in ebc12e0b9e33 mkdir : An item with he specified name C:\temp already exists.`

Whenever i try to rebuild the image it gives me the error the directory already exists. which (when rebuilding) should not exist right?

Comment: @LlamaNL No if there is an error when building the image it must be fixed. The error will appear at each rebuild. From my understanding you builded the image with no modification it worked. Then you customized the dockerfile and build fails at step 3 `RUN mkdir C:\temp`. You also tried with --no-cache flag to ensure that the error was not linked to cache. It might sound stupid but try to rebuild the image without creating the temp folder. It's seems that the image has already the temp folder : https://github.com/microsoft/mssql-docker/tree/master/windows/mssql-server-windows-developer

Comment: That's just it, the FIRST build works just fine. When i try to build again it errors out

Comment: Best answer on StackOverflow